# Matlab - make one point move towards another

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, model, simulation

I need to program a dot moving towards another dot. I have the initial coords of the point, however the point at which it has to move to is randomly selected.Eg the initial of the dot might me [0 0], and it will have to travel to [100,325] or [198,-243]. The grid within which the points can spawn has bound of 500 and -500 (square).

Currently generating points using,

```
dots = plot(XY(:,1), XY(:,2), ...
        'Marker', '.', ...
        'Color', 'b', ...
        'LineStyle', 'none', ...
        'MarkerSize', 6);
```

and giving them XY coordinates with (initially random within a small starting area). In this case numberDots is = 1 (have to add more later). baseRadius = 50

```
angle = rand(numberUAVs, 1) * 2*pi;
r = baseRadius * sqrt(rand(numberDots, 1));
XY = [r .* cos(angle(:)) + 0, ...
      r .* sin(angle(:)) + 0]
```

This is how im currently trying to get them to move by simply adding 1 to the coords and plotting.

```
for i = 1:1000000
    XY = XY + 1;
    pause(0.1)
    set(dots, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
end
```

How can make the dot move towards a randomly defined point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding `1` to you x/y coordinates each time through the loop will work only if your new point is *always* to the upper right of your current point with the same x and y distance from your start point.

Instead, you can simply use [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) to get linearly spaced `x` values between the start and finish and similarly for `y` values.

```
%// Number of "steps" you want to take to get from the start point to the end point
nSteps = 100;

%// Figure out all intermediate x/y values between the two
xx = linspace(x_start, x_end, nSteps);
yy = linspace(y_start, y_end, nSteps);

%// Create the initial plot
plt = plot(NaN, NaN, 'bo');

%// Then plot the point's path
for k = 1:nSteps
    set(plt, 'XData', xx(k), 'YData', yy(k))
    drawnow;
end
```